# Does python have large overhead in using python's data structure?

Tags: python, heap-memory

Compared to non-script languages such as C, **python** makes extensive use of data structure such as List, Set, Dictionary, or whatever that are related to dynamic memory.

However, as far as I know, all these data structures are allocated in heap memory. In addition, in these data structure, appending and deleting are frequently used in python applications, which could be similar to frequent usage of C's malloc, free, or resizing malloc.

It seems that all these actions will cause significant overheads.

Do python use special optimization for this? or Doesn't it generate overhead?

Comment: Unless you're writing under MISRA rules or something, you're going to make extensive use of dynamic allocation in C and C++ too, and idiomatic C++ involves plenty of use of classes like `std::vector`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_set`, etc. that fulfill similar roles to Python data structures.

Comment: @user2357112 (I removed the C++ in my question)The thing that I want to focus was that compared to other languages, python basically uses these data structures and want to figure out python has its optimization for this.

Comment: As a general rule, Python is completely inappropriate for the kinds of programs where allocation an array on the heap instead of the stack is going to be a bottleneck. Even if you allocated a list on the stack, that would be an array of pointers to objects that box up the actual values. And looping over that list will require going through an interpreted function call for each element. And then unboxing each value to do anything with it. And so on.

Comment: Usually, you can deal with this by using a library like NumPy, or writing custom C (or Cython, C++, etc.) extensions to take the inner loops out of Python, and in the outer loops it no longer matters whether you waste a microsecond here or there. If you can't organize your code that way (which is rare, but not never), you basically can't use Python for that project.

Answer (score 1):

In Python (as in the standard libraries of many other languages) these dynamic data structures are implemented in a way that amortizes costs of memory allocation over repeated calls to append and delete.  So, for example, a list over-allocates memory in proportion to its size, as documented in this [implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/273e17260d25/Objects/listobject.c#l42).